# How can I clear a stubborn browser cache in Safari, Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: browser, vbscript, cross-browser

I have several ASP pages that refuse to reload showing the latest changes in several browsers.

I have placed

```
 Response.expires = -1 
 Response.CacheControl = "Private"
 Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
```

at the top of each page.

I have also placed

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

inside the html head area.

In Safari, Chrome and Firefox each page loads fine the first time. But if I make a change to the file, large or small, the cached file reappears even though I have religiously used the cache clearing techniques recommended for each browser. I have ftp downloaded the files and indeed they show the changes.

Has anyone else experienced such a thing?

I am using Mac 10.12.5, Safari 10.1.1, Chrome 59.0.3071.115, Firefox 54.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be affected by a couple of things here.

One is your IIS instance's caching settings. If you're able to open IIS Manager, go to your website instance and open up the 'Output Caching' feature, check if there's anything in this list that could affect your asp files.

If that doesn't work, I suspect your issue is FTP. You mentioned you were using FTP to download the files. If you are using them to *upload* your files too, you might find that your client is not updating the timestamp on those files (I have had this issue before). When ASP runs a script, it caches the compiled version to reuse later, which saves time. If the file's timestamp doesn't change, ASP will continue to use its precompiled version instead of recompiling the new file. You must force the timestamp to be updated if possible (some FTP clients have an option for this). Failing that, deleting and recreating the file should work.

Comment: @user2016210 Glad that worked for you! Was it the FTP timestamps?